# nextcloud with s3: I get a lot of files in the bucket although I have uploaded 2 files

Tags: amazon-s3, nextcloud

I have configured nextcloud with **AWS S3** and it's working fine, however when I upload a file I get only the correct file displayed in the dashboard but in the bucket I get a lot of files in form of `urn:oid:<some-id>`

this is my dashboard:
[image]

This is my bucket:
[image]

As you can see I get 20 file in the bucket.
After invetigation I found that the `id` in `urn:oid:<id>` is coming from the database which nextcloud is using (which is mysql in my case) from the `oc_filecache` table and it does contain a lot of rows even way more than the number of files in the bucket!

Not sure why all these information from nextcloud, and how can I make it display only the files I upload in s3, you know for cost managment reasons :)